# Duplicate push notification at a time send via firebase

Tags: django, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I face a weird problem, with push notifications using Firebase and Django fcm-device. When a file upload is done, then push notification to desired users. I ensure that this function calls only one time after the video upload is completed. Suddenly 20-30 notifications are sent for one single upload to desired users. This issue stays approx 5-10h. But now it's fine again, no problems. Then what would be the reason for this behavior? This problem happened few hours after we changed from free plan (Spark) to Pay as you go plan (BLAZE)